# Undefined Frame topmost() after changing system font-size in Android

Tags: android, navigation, nativescript, font-size

I have an issue in my native script application on Android : After leaving the app and changing the system font size, I cannot use my navigation bar. The error is the following :

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onTouch failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

It seems like the frame becomes undefined or inaccessible via frame.topmost. This error only appears when I want to use the navigation as first action after going back to the app. When I leave the app and go back there without changing the system font-size in between the error also does not occur.

I am running the app in an android simulator, using different version of Android (8,9,9+). The problem seems to be independent of the android version.

Nativescript is Version 6.1.2

This issue is reproducible in the app-template "tns-template-drawer-navigation" : 
Create a project using this template by calling

```
tns create my-app-name --template tns-template-drawer-navigation
```

Run the app in the android simulator. Next, open the android settings and change the font-size. After that, switching back to the app, opening the side-menu and tapping one of the menu-items will cause the error.

Is there any idea how to solve this rare issue?

Bests,
Julian

Comment: topmost exists only on Frame module not on page instance. Can you setup a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: True that, sorry for this. Of course I mean frame.topmost...I will try to create a minimal example

Comment: I added an example to the main question

Comment: It will be easier if you setup a Playground which doesn't require a local setup, easy for anyone to take a quick peak on browser itself.